# convert a php code to objective C

Tags: php, objective-c, ios4

can someone please help me out writing this code in objective C :

```
function extractStringFromString ($string, $start, $end) {

    $startPos = strpos($string,$start);
    $stringEndTagPos = strpos($string,$end,$startPos);
    $stringBetween = substr($string,$startPos+strlen($start),$stringEndTagPos-$startPos-strlen($start));

    if (strlen($stringBetween) != 0) {

        return $stringBetween;
        return true;
    }
    else {

        return false;
    }

}
```

what the function does is simple, takes 3 values, `$string` which is a text and `$start` and `$end` which the function will look for in the text (`$start` will be the start of the search, and once start is found, `$end` will be the end of the search and it will return the value)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searches first `start` string and last `end` string

```
- (NSString *)extractStringFromString:(NSString *)string start:(NSString *)start end:(NSString *)end
{
    NSRange indexStart = [string rangeOfString:start];
    if (indexStart.location == NSNotFound) return nil;

    NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(indexStart.location + indexStart.length, [string length] - indexStart.location - indexStart.length);
    NSRange indexEnd = [string rangeOfString:end options:NSBackwardsSearch range:searchRange];
    if (indexEnd.location == NSNotFound) return nil;

    return [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(indexStart.location + indexStart.length, indexEnd.location - indexStart.location - indexStart.length)];
}
```

Searches first `start` string and first `end` string after first `start` string:

```
- (NSString *)extractStringFromString:(NSString *)string start:(NSString *)start end:(NSString *)end
{
    NSRange indexStart = [string rangeOfString:start];
    if (indexStart.location == NSNotFound) return nil;

    NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(indexStart.location + indexStart.length, [string length] - indexStart.location - indexStart.length);
    NSRange indexEnd = [string rangeOfString:end options:NSLiteralSearch range:searchRange];
    if (indexEnd.location == NSNotFound) return nil;

    return [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(indexStart.location + indexStart.length, indexEnd.location - indexStart.location - indexStart.length)];
}
```

Comment: thanks alot man, the line "return [string..." returns an error (program received signal "sigabrt") , any idea why?? :)

Comment: Give me, please, the example of your call. (input strings)

Comment: this is the code :

   
 NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://radarurl.com/url/twtio.com"]];
    
    NSString *siteID = [self extractStringFromString:html start:@"var SITE_ID = " end:@";"];

Comment: hey thanks, now it doesnt return an error but it doesnt return the right string, it actually returns the entire html page (if you test it on xcode)

Comment: Check your test data. I've tested it and it works fine. Use NSLog() for checking values of all input strings.

Comment: hey thanks alot, it works but for the ending it looks for the last possible value and then returns that, I need it to find the next result right after the start is found!

Answer (score 4):

```
-(NSString*)extractStringFromString:(NSString*)text fromIndex(NSInteger)start toIndex:(NSInteger)end{
    NSRange cropRange = {start, [text length] - end};
    return [text substringWithRange: cropRange];

}
```

But of course you should really just use:

```
    NSRange cropRange = {aStartIndex, aLength};
    NSString* substring = [text substringWithRange: cropRange];
```

Comment: They are not equivalent. You are not searching for substring indexes.